# Discord-Mumble bot TEXT CHANNEL

Tags: python, text, discord, bots, mumble-web

I'm trying to make a discord bot that sends mumble messages to a discord channel but I can't do it

this is the code:

```
import asyncio
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from pymumble_py3 import Mumble

# Configuración
mumble_host = "IP"
mumble_port = 64738
mumble_username = "USER"
mumble_password = "PASS"
mumble_channel_id = "CHANNEL"
discord_token = "TOKEN"
discord_channel_id = "ID"
cert_path = "/rute/to/cert.crt"
key_path = "rute/to/key.pem"

# Crear objeto intents
#intents = discord.Intents.default()
#intents.members = True
#intents.guilds = True
intents = discord.Intents.all()

# Crear cliente de Mumble con certificado y clave privada
mumble = Mumble(mumble_host, mumble_username, mumble_port, certfile=cert_path, keyfile=key_path, password=mumble_password)
mumble.start()
mumble.is_ready()
mumble.channels.find_by_name(mumble_channel_id).move_in()

# Crear bot de Discord
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!", intents=intents)

# Evento de conexión
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print(f"{bot.user.name} está conectado a Discord.")

# Escuchar mensajes desde Mumble
async def mumble_text_received(message):
    if not isinstance(message.actor, dict) or "name" not in message.actor:
        return

    if message.actor["name"] == mumble_username:
        return

    text = f"[Mumble] {message.actor['name']}: {message.message}"
    await send_discord_message(text)

# Enviar mensajes a Discord
async def send_discord_message(text):
    channel = bot.get_channel(discord_channel_id)
    if channel is not None:
        await channel.send(text)
    else:
        print(f"No se pudo encontrar el canal con ID {discord_channel_id}.")

# Establecer callback en el cliente de Mumble
def set_mumble_callback():
    message = None
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)
    asyncio.ensure_future(mumble_text_received(message))
    mumble.callbacks.set_callback("text_received", lambda msg: setattr(message, "message", msg.message))
    
# Comando para activar el bot en Discord
@bot.command()
async def active(ctx):
    global discord_channel_id
    discord_channel_id = ctx.channel.id
    await ctx.send(f"BotText activado en el canal {ctx.channel.mention} de Discord.")    

# Iniciar bot de Discord
bot.run(discord_token)
```

When I run the bot, it connects correctly to discord and mumble but does not auto - send the messages that are registered in the mumble channel to the discord channel, is there something I forgot?
I hope someone can find the key since such a function would be very beneficial for the community

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.